# extjs6.2.0 draw sprite scrollable does not work

Tags: extjs6.2

I use extjs 6.2.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oePZd.png) 'xtye: draw' to implements on topology. Need to scrollbar to show customer all sprites when some of sprites out of screen. However, even I configured scrollable to true, it does not work.

I simplified the codes by create two circles in one container to reproduce this issue, please check codes below for the reference.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Ext.define('drawtest.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

```
requires: [
    'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',

    'drawtest.view.main.MainController',
    'drawtest.view.main.MainModel',
    'drawtest.view.main.List',
    'Ext.draw.plugin.SpriteEvents',
    'Ext.draw.Container'
],

controller: 'main',
viewModel: 'main',

ui: 'navigation',


items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    layout: 'border',
    scrollable: 'true',
    items: [{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'draw',
        scrollable: true,
        plugins: ['spriteevents'],
        // /scrollable: 'true',

        margin: '1 0 0 1',
        flex: 1,
        reference: 'windmachines',
        sprites: [{
            type: 'circle',
            fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
            r: 100,
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        }, {
            type: 'circle',
            fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
            r: 100,
            x: 1900,
            y: 100
        }],
    }]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have to put values for the width/height of the draw container to fit all your sprites:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        scrollable:true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [ {
                xtype: 'draw',
                width: 2100,
                height: 500,
                sprites: [{
                    type: 'circle',
                    fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
                    r: 100,
                    x: 100,
                    y: 100
                }, {
                    type: 'circle',
                    fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
                    r: 100,
                    x: 1900,
                    y: 100
                }]

        }]
    });
```

Consider that **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2i1u&view/editor)**

Comment: Your codes work beautifully, you save my day. Appreciated!